# How to show/hide dropdown when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, checkbox

I need use JavaScript, but I'm new to it. I use php mostly. When checkbox is selected (to choose definite role in registration) - dependently of the role that you have chosen, to be shown or not 2 dropdowns. If you have chosen Student, I want not to be shown these 2 dropdowns - for school and class, if you have chosen teacher - to be shown.I'm using Codeigniter. That's my view:

```html
<html>
<head>

   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<?php
   echo "<body>";
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo form_open();
 
  echo "<h3>Register</h3><br/>";  
  echo "<table border = '0' >";
  echo "<tr><td>  Username:* </td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'class' => form_error('username') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_input($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td> Password:* </td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'password',
    'class' => form_error('password') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_password($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";
  
  echo "<tr><td>  Choose role:*  </td><td>";

  echo form_checkbox('role_id[]', '1');
  echo " Student ";
  echo form_checkbox('role_id[]', '2');
  echo " Teacher";
  echo "</td></tr>";


  echo "<tr><td>  School:*  </td><td>";
  $options=array(
    'pmg' => 'Harvard',
    'eg' => 'Cambridge',
    'class' => form_error('school[]') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_dropdown('school[]',$options);
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>  Class:*  </td><td>";
  $options=array(
    '8' => '8',
    '9' => '9',
    'class' => form_error('class[]') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_dropdown('class[]',$options);
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "</table><br/>";
  $data=array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-success ',
    'value' => 'Register'
  );
  echo form_submit($data);
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
```

Comment: It could be easier to help you, if you will show the generated html. Most probably the problem can be solved using only CSS :-)

Comment: it looks in that way:   http://prntscr.com/6kokrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>

   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(self, show){
        if (show)
            $('.toggle').show();
        else
            $('.toggle').hide();
        $(":checkbox").prop('checked',false);
        $(self).prop('checked',true);
    }
    </script>   
</head>
<?php
   echo "<body>";
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo form_open();

  echo "<h3>Register</h3><br/>";  
  echo "<table border = '0' >";
  echo "<tr><td>  Username:* </td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'class' => form_error('username') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_input($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td> Password:* </td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'password',
    'class' => form_error('password') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_password($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td>  Choose role:*  </td><td>";

  echo form_checkbox('role_id[]', '1', FALSE, 'onClick="showHide(this, false)"');
  echo " Student ";
  echo form_checkbox('role_id[]', '2', FALSE, 'onClick="showHide(this, true)"');
  echo " Teacher";
  echo "</td></tr>";


  echo "<tr class='toggle' style='display:none;'><td>  School:*  </td><td>";
  $options=array(
    'pmg' => 'Harvard',
    'eg' => 'Cambridge',
    'class' => form_error('school[]') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_dropdown('school[]',$options);
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr class='toggle' style='display:none;'><td>  Class:*  </td><td>";
  $options=array(
    '8' => '8',
    '9' => '9',
    'class' => form_error('class[]') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_dropdown('class[]',$options);
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "</table><br/>";
  $data=array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-success ',
    'value' => 'Register'
  );
  echo form_submit($data);
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
```

Two functionalities are added:

1. Dropdowns are initially hidden, until you select "Teacher" checkbox
2. Checking one checkbox will uncheck the other

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc0eu0xd/). Tested in FF, IE 11, Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! It works great! I had to write more code..it helps me much!